# Image is getting added automatically in UItableView Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

Helo all,

I am having a very strange situation here.I have a table view in which i have custom cells. So i have designed my own custom cell.In custom cell i am displaying the image as well text.The data of table comes from server.If any image in json then image will be displayed else only text is displayed.So cell will dynamic.I have used `bezier path` to wrap text around image.No if image is there so text will be wrapped.When i add new post from server with image & i refresh the table then it automatically display the image for other post as well.It will display the same image which is same image for last.I don;t know why new cell is adding image in it's cell even the code works fine i have dbugged it using breakpoints.Please tell what could be the issue.

Here is code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //define variables here
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";
    HomeCell *cell = [tableView
                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    if([arr_post count]>0)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr;
        NSAttributedString *attributeStr;

        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        //get the post data
        Post *user_post=[arr_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //set the button tags
        cell.btn_like.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.btn_comment.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.btn_fav.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.btn_con.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.btn_book.tag=indexPath.row;

        //add info to buttons
        cell.btn_like.selected=user_post.isPostLiked;
        cell.btn_comment.selected=user_post.isPostCommented;
        cell.btn_fav.selected=user_post.isPostFavourite;
        cell.btn_con.selected=user_post.isPostCondolence;
        cell.btn_book.selected=user_post.isPostBookmarked;

        //add user info
        cell.label_name.text=user_post.username;
        cell.img_profile.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
        cell.img_profile.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.img_profile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.user_profileImage]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
        //add location
        if([user_post.location isEqualToString:@"Not Available"])
        {
            [cell.img_icon_location setHidden:true];
            [cell.label_location setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.img_icon_location setHidden:false];
            [cell.label_location setHidden:false];
            cell.label_location.text=user_post.location;
        }
        //ad post info
        cell.tv_post.text=user_post.post_description;
        cell.tv_post.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user_post.font_family size:[user_post.font_size floatValue]];
        [cell.tv_post setTextColor:[self colorFromHexString:user_post.font_color]];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:user_post.modification_date];
        NSLog(@"user post image is %@",user_post.post_image);

        if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {

            NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"INSIDE BEIZER PATH CONDITION");
            UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
            cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
            UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];

            if(![user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
            {
                [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_image]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

            }
            if(![user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
            {
                [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

            }

            [cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image];
        }
        //make textview height dynamic
        cell.tv_post.scrollEnabled=NO;
        if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            CGFloat fixedWidth = cell.tv_post.frame.size.width;
            CGSize newSize = [cell.tv_post sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
            CGRect newFrame = cell.tv_post.frame;
            newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
            cell.tv_post.frame = newFrame;
            cell.tv_height.constant=cell.tv_post.frame.size.height;
            [cell.view_tvContainer layoutIfNeeded];
        }
               //set the border of uiview
        cell.view_tvContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.view_tvContainer.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

        //set the like count
        NSString *first_like_user=recent_like_name=user_post.recent_like_name;
        NSLog(@"FIRST LIEK USER IS %@",first_like_user);
        NSString *str_recent_like_name;
        int count=(int)[first_like_user length];
        int like_count=[user_post.like_count intValue];
        if(like_count>0)
        {
            cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [cell.label_like_count sizeToFit];
            [cell.label_like_count setHidden:false];
            NSString *str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count-1];
            if(like_count==1)
            {
                if([myUsername isEqualToString:first_like_user])
                {
                    first_like_user=@"You like this post ";
                    count=3;
                }
                else
                {
                    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" like this post"];
                }
            }
            else if(like_count==2)
            {
                if([first_like_user isEqualToString:myUsername])
                {
                    first_like_user=@"You";
                }
                Post *temp_user_post=[copy_arr_user_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                if(temp_user_post.recent_like_name==nil)
                {
                    temp_user_post.recent_like_name=@"";
                }
                str_recent_like_name=[temp_user_post.recent_like_name_two stringByAppendingString:@" like this post"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_recent_like_name];
            }
            else
            {
                if(like_count>1000)
                {
                    like_count=like_count/1000;
                    str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count];
                    str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@"k"];
                    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                    str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];
                }
                else
                {
                    if([first_like_user isEqualToString:myUsername])
                    {
                        first_like_user=@"You";
                    }
                    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                    str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];
                }
            }
            mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:first_like_user];
            attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

            [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
            [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

            [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

            [cell.label_like_count setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.label_like_count setHidden:true];


        }
        // show dynamic comment
        NSMutableArray *user_comments=user_post.comments;
        float comment_count=[user_post.comment_count intValue];
         NSLog(@"ID IS %@",user_post.id);
        if(comment_count>0)
        {
            //make label multiline
            cell.first_comment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [cell.first_comment sizeToFit];
            cell.second_cmment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [cell.second_cmment sizeToFit];
            cell.third_comment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [cell.third_comment sizeToFit];

            if(comment_count==1)
            {
                [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
                [cell.second_cmment setHidden:true];
                [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];

            }
            else if(comment_count==2)
            {
                [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
                [cell.second_cmment setHidden:false];
                [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];

            }
            else
            {
                [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
                [cell.second_cmment setHidden:false];
                [cell.third_comment setHidden:false];
                [cell.btn_more_comments setHidden:false];

            }
            for(l=0;l<[user_comments count];l++)
            {
                Comment *comment=[user_comments objectAtIndex:l];
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];
                NSAttributedString *attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                // end of the repetitive pattern
                if (l == 0)
                {
                    [cell.first_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
                }
                else if (l == 1)
                {
                    [cell.second_cmment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
                }
                else if (l == 2)
                {
                    [cell.third_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.first_comment setHidden:true];
            [cell.second_cmment setHidden:true];
            [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];
            [cell.btn_more_comments removeFromSuperview];
        }
        cell.label_time.text=[BaseController timeAgoStringFromDate:date];
        [arr_indexpath addObject:indexPath];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Cell objects are reused. You need to make sure that you remove any old image before reusing the cell

Comment: How can i do that.I have been searching this for more a week but people have been syaing cell reuse,cellreuse,cell resuse.Nut not able to find a singkle solution & morever a good overview of the problem.Can you please tell me what best i can do it.Please

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `addSubview` so, you will,find it hard to find a reference to remove it later. You should include the imageview in your cell and hide/unhide it as required

Comment: can you please provide me with the code.sso i can have better understsaning.I am not a experineced developer.just strated with ios

Comment: for wrapping text around image i am using beizer path that i why i am adding image view that is what i have to do i if i want to wrap text around image.

Comment: You should have the imageview in your cell just like your labels etc - defined in the storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93226/discussion-between-paulw11-and-deepak-kumar).

Comment: I can make image view static in stroy board because i am using bezier path.check my code.I am creating a beizer path fro image view in that path i add an image for wrapping text around image.so is there any other solution you have?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the cells is reused. If you have, say, 10000 rows in your table datasource, the table view won't create that many rows. It will only create enough rows to be displayed on the screen and a few others to be preloaded.
For every time you scroll your table, the tableview will use those cells that go invisible to load the new cells that just become visible, to make a illusion of infinite amount of rows. That why those new cells have the old data. So basically, you will have to set your `UIImageView`'s image to `nil` in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` if no image is available.

```
if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {

            NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");

        }
```

In the code of you above, you simply print out a log, while what you also have to do is setting the `UIImageView's` image to `nil`.

So this is my suggestion:

```
//if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
//{

//   NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");

//}
//else
{
    NSLog(@"INSIDE BEIZER PATH CONDITION");
    UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
    cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
    UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];

    if(![user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_image]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

    }
    else{
        [tv_image setImage:nil]; //Prevent the old data to be shown
    }

    if(![user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

    }
    else{
        [tv_image setImage:nil];//Prevent the old data to be shown
    }

    [cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image];
}
```

Maybe this code doesn't fit your requirements about how the data will be displayed, but hope it helps you to get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

When a tableview cell is needed to be displayed you will either create a new one or reuse one that you created previously but is no longer visible on screen. Since you have created a `UIImageView` and added it to a cell, when you reuse it the image is still there.

To stop this happening, you need to keep a reference to the imageview so the next time around you are able to remove it. Since you are adding them dynamically and don't have an `IBOutlet` your quickest option is to assign the image a `tag`

```
UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
tv_image.tag = 21; // arbitrary number but must be unique to the image
```

By tagging the image, the next time around you can get access to it:

```
UIImageView *tv_image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:21];
if (tv_image != nil) {
    tv_image.image = nil; // remove the image (or remove the image view from the cell etc)
}
```

Just be sure to refactor the code accordingly so that if you find the image from a tag you don't need to recreate it etc

Comment: Put the second block I posted immediately after you fetch your cell (HomeCell *cell = ...) to clear the image. Then, where you create tv_image you apply the tag to it. If tv_image is not nil, you can skip the initWithFrame and tag etc since it will be using the recycled version

Answer (score 0):

Your `img_profile` is getting repeated because your are re-using the cell.

Replace the below line of code

```
[cell.img_profile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.user_profileImage]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
```

with below code:-

```
    if (user_post.user_profileImage.length == 0) {
        cell.img_profile.hidden = true;
    }else{
        [cell.img_profile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.user_profileImage]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
    }
```

*Explanation:-*
Check if your json contains the user profile image then set the image, else hide the profile image view.

Answer (score 0):

A table view **reuses** cells. This means that if you add a subview to a cell, as you do on the line `[cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image]`, then **that subview will still be in the cell when it is reused**.

Basically, if you are adding subviews to a custom cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you are probably making a mistake.

Just design the `tv_image` view into the `HomeCell` in the first place. `HomeView` should have an outlet named `tv_image`, connected to the image view in your storyboard or XIB. When you need `tv_image`, show it. Otherwise, hide it.

```
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {

        NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");
        cell.tv_image.image = nil;
        cell.tv_image.hidden = YES;
        cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"INSIDE BEIZER PATH CONDITION");
        UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
        cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];

        if(![user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [cell.tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_image]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }
        if(![user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [cell.tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }

        cell.tv_image.hidden = NO;
    }
```

Also, make sure `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` doesn't set the image view's `hidden = NO` when it loads the image.

Comment: How to remove beizer path from every new textview.You see here i am also adding beizer path into the textview so when image is removed beizer path must be removed

Comment: I can't design from storyboard because i am using beizer path so i want to wrap text around image here.

Comment: Then create the image view (and add it as as subview) in your `HomeCell` code and store it in a property so you can access it in your table view controller. I've updated my code to reset `exclusionPaths` to an empty array when there's no `tv_image` to display.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder where you are allocating you custom cell. Shouldn't you be creating cell only if it's not created. Something like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";
HomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];
}
```

And then updating the UI components.

```
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {

        NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"INSIDE BEIZER PATH CONDITION");
        UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
        cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
        UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];

        if(![user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_image]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }
        if(![user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }

        [cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image];
    }
```

perhaps you should write an "update method" inside your "HomeCell" class. To update the UI components.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [SDWebImage][1]https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage , where you can update your cell in completion block or cache image if need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two folds:

1. cells are reused, this is common place for miss, but not in your case.
2. your line `[cell.img_profile setImageWithURL:...];` is **asynchronous**, which mean by the time the image is downloaded, your cell may be reused, so clearing the imageView *at reuse* won't help.

To properly use async-loading of image in a reusable cell, you have to double check that it's the correct image *on loading success*.

add a property to the cell class:

```
@property (weak) NSURL *targetImageUrl;
```

then change the loading to add a check:

```
NSURL *targetImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.user_profileImage]];

cell.targetImageUrl = targetImageUrl; // <!> replace latest target
[cell.img_profile
    setImageWithURLRequest: [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:targetImageUrl]
    placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]
    success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        if (cell.targetImageUrl != targetImageUrl) return; // <!> this is the trick

        cell.img_profile.image = image;
    }
    failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called whenever the cell becomes visible, I always use the next strategy for displaying images that need to be loaded from the web: I either associate the image (when downloaded) with objc_setAssociatedObject with the object that contains data for table row, or create some hashMap where i put the images with some id for the key. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath I check if associated object is nil (or if image for the key exists in hashmap). If it's nil or doesn't exist (which means it's still downloading) i set a placeholder image for the imageView's image, otherwise I set the downloaded image.
And after download you reload table (or just the needed cell)